# How would I make batch code running in a command prompt window unclosable?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I'm looking to make a file that when running it constantly kills chrome so you cannot run it **(this is just for fun)** and I'm trying to make it so it is not possible to just close it by hitting the **X** button

Would it be possible?

```
cls
:kill
taskkill /IM chrome.exe
goto kill
```

Comment: @SebastíanMontoya do you have the code for that (sry deleted first comment i thought i did the @ wrong)

Comment: Your use of `taskkill.exe`, does not stop an end user from running `chrome.exe`, all it does is close it, if it has been launched. If I tried to launch an application, and it didn't launch, I'd take a look to see what was stopping it, and even with a hidden Command Prompt window, I'm sure it wouldn't take long for me to determine that was the likely cause, and kill that process. I wouldn't need to close a window with its 'X button'. The best way to achieve your goal would be to uninstall it, from their system. _That would usually be classed as malicious, but chrome is malware, so it is fine_.

Answer (score 0):

Well Windows command prompt don't let you do that.

However another languages like [Python](https://python.org) can do that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Right now your response doesn't really answer the question.